# CSS Background color doesn't work unless a height is specified or it's floated?

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

Can anyone explain why on the 3rd line of the CSS in this JFiddle [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eJS6b/)  why the div ID of #form_container requires a height in order for the background to show if a float:left is specified at line 14?

I thought floats did not remove objects from the flow of the browser...

```
<div id="form_container">
<form id="contact_form" action="#" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <p>
        <label for="byour_name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="byour_name" value="" id="byour_name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="byour_email_address">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="byour_email_address" value="" id="byour_email_address">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
        <input type="text" name="formsubject" value="" id="form_subject">
    </p>
    <p>Message:
        <br/>
        <textarea id="form_messagebox" name="Message" rows="20" cols="25"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Send it!">
    </p>
</form>
```

CSS

```
    #form_container {
    width: 300px;
   /* height: 300px; Background works with this uncommented if the float is enabled*/
    border: 2px red solid;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    background-color: red !important;
}
#form_container form {
    color: black;
}
#form_container input, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding 0;
    float:left; /* This breaks the background */
    display:inline;
}
#form_container label {
    width: 200px;
    position:relative;
}
#submitBtn {

}
#contact input, textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0px 1px 4px 0px;
    background-color: rgb(221, 220, 219);
    font: normal normal normal 16px/1.3em'open sans', sans-serif;
    border: 0px solid rgb(192, 185, 181);
}
#form_messagebox {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is fiddle of your que see this

http://jsfiddle.net/jkkheni/eJS6b/3/

added a css class of clear

```
 .clear{ clear:both; height:0px; width:0px; display:table; content:"";}
```

and added a div in your html

```
  <div class="clear"></div>
```

before closing div with id `form_container`

when you use float always clear all float.
or you can also use `overflow:hidden` in div with `form_container` id

Answer (score 1):

`float` removes height of the element if it is not specified.

Try:

```
#form_container{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/eJS6b/1/)

OR

clear floats after finishing form:

```
<div class="clr"></div>
.clr{clear:both;}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/eJS6b/2/)